# How to Find Greater value between two numbers in reactjc

Tags: reactjs

I am beginner in React. I would like to find greater than values to using states. I do not have an idea how to define values inside setStates.

```
import React from 'react';
class `Greatersum e`xtends React.Component
{
  constructor(props)
  {
        super(props);
        this.state={
                    a:'',
                    b:'',
                    c:''
                    }
            this.addFormData=this.addFormData.bind(this);
    }
          addFormData()
          {
            this.setState({c:('this.state.a?')(':this.state.b')});
          }
          render()
          {
            return(

                <div>
                  <input type="text" ***onChange=***{e=> this.setState({a:e.target.value})}/><br/><br/>
                  <input type="text" onChange={e=> this.setState({b:e.target.value})}/><br/><br/>
                  <input type="text" value={this.state.c}/><br/><br/>
                  <button type="submit" onClick={this.addFormData}>Click Me</button>
                </div>
              )
 };
}
export default Greatersum;**strong text**
```

Answer (score 2):

**1)** You should first convert it to `number` type as

```
onChange={(e) => this.setState({ a: +e.target.value })}
```

**Live Demo**

[image: Codesandbox Demo]

**2)** Get the largest of two as:

```
addFormData() {
    this.setState((state) => ({ c: state.a > state.b ? state.a : state.b }));
}
```

> **Note: If you are just using `c` for displaying text, then you shouldn't use `input`. If you still want to use `input` then can make it
> uncontrolled input and set value using `React.createRef`**

[image: Codesandbox Demo]